# to close login form and open forms depending on user credentials

Tags: c#

I have a login form . After successful login ,depending on the credentials,the user is directed to different forms. For example : if the user is the admin , the adminform should appear , if the user is storekeeper ,the storekeeper form etc ...

I have implemented the login form and its being redirected accordingly .But the problem is I have used this.hide() to hide the login form and if i try to close the storekeeper/admin/manager form the application continues to run as the login form is hiding.

also in login form the close button or X prompts the user:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }



if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to Quit the Application?", "Quit Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

        else
        {
            txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

}

I have read through different articles but they all have the main form after login and so it is called in **application.run(new Mainform())** after the login.showdialog()....

hoping for some guidance..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
```

This should terminate your application, regardless of hidden forms.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It does work ...But as mentioned in the question.. when i click on close of the storekeeper form it prompts the user and when user clicks on YES again the same prompt appears which is of the Login form as it is not closed but hidden ..

Comment: You could pass the login form as a reference to the other forms, and when closing, you could set a property in login form which states that the form is closing, and that it should not prompt the user again for confirmation.